# jQuery delay fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript/jquery slideshow but I want to remove the somewhat long blank nothingness in between the `fadein` and `fadeout` images.  I tried using a small `delay` because by default it still had a blank pause but that didn't work, any idea?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/s624zn7d/1/

```js
var imagesArray = ["http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png",
                   "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png",
                   "https://assets.pokemon.com/static2/_ui/img/account/sign-up.png",
                   "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/0/6087/2438704-1202149925_t.png",
                   "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/0/6087/2438704-1202149925_t.png"];

function preloadImg(pictureUrls, callback) {
  var i, j, loaded = 0;
  var imagesArray = [];

  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    imagesArray.push(new Image());
  }
  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    (function (img, src) {
      img.onload = function () {
        if (++loaded == pictureUrls.length && callback) {
          callback(imagesArray);
        }
      };
      img.src = src;
    }(imagesArray[i], pictureUrls[i]));
  }
};


function roll(imagesArray, currentPos){

  var slide = $('.parallax-mirror').find('img').attr('src', imagesArray[currentPos].src);
  slide.fadeIn(2000, function() {
    slide.fadeOut(1500, function() {
      currentPos++;
      if(currentPos >= imagesArray.length){
        currentPos = 0;
      }
      roll(imagesArray, currentPos);
    });
  });
}

$(function () {
  preloadImg(imagesArray, function (imagesArray) {
    roll(imagesArray, 0, 3);
  });
});
```

```css
.featured-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.things {
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>

<div class="featured-wrapper" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png">

</div>
<div class="things">I'm the stuff underneath</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an opacity animation with an easing that fits your needs. You can use  [jquery ui easings](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)